# howto form code documentation from your comments in php

Tags: php, documentation

I'm trying to remember the name of a method of commenting your php code inline that auto forms very nice documentation when you're done. Can anyone help me, I thought it was code folding, but I can't seem to dig it up now.

Thanks,

Comment: Also see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/189516/automatic-php-documentation-generation http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1182781/how-do-you-document-your-php-functions-and-classes-inline

Answer (score 0):

You're probably looking for a documentation generator like [doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl).
It can parse your source code files and extract function/class definitions with related comments from it.

Answer (score 0):

Look into [phpDocumentor](http://www.phpdoc.org/) - probably it is what you are looking for.